# The `ubuntu-security-status` command claims that almost all "packages are from third parties"

Tags: package-management, upgrade, arm, 22.04

I have an Ubuntu (Arm *aarch64*) system upgraded from 21.10 to 22.04 (development) and now finally to 22.04 (release). The output of the command `ubuntu-security-status` is something like this:

```
1910 packages installed, of which:
   0 receive package updates with LTS until 4/2027
1906 packages are from third parties
   4 packages are no longer available for download
[...]
```

I have another ***similarly upgraded*** (but, Intel *x86_64*) system where the same command displays something like:

```
2201 packages installed, of which:
1900 receive package updates with LTS until 4/2027
   1 package is from a third party
   3 packages are no longer available for download
[...]
```

I am expecting `ubuntu-security-status` command on the Arm system to display those 1900+ packages to "`receive package updates with LTS until 4/2027`" as on the Intel system. Why does the `ubuntu-security-status` command give this unexpected output?

Note: Both systems are fully up-to-date and the `apt` (`update`, `upgrade`, ...) commands work as expected on both systems: Both systems are able to normally install OS patches.

The Arm system is an Oracle cloud server with "Ubuntu Desktop" software installed and the output of the command `grep -v -e '^#' -e '^ *$' /etc/apt/sources.list` is:

```
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy main restricted
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates main restricted
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy universe
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates universe
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy multiverse
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-updates multiverse
deb http://eu-frankfurt-1-ad-3.clouds.ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ jammy-backports main restricted  universe multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security main restricted
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports jammy-security multiverse
```

Comment: Do you use a local mirror on the system with the issue? If so, I can supply the fix.

Comment: @OrganicMarble : I updated the question. I do not use any local mirror.

Comment: Limitation of the tool, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Per my contacts on the Security team, `arm64` is in the ports.ubuntu.com repository.  Unfortunately, the `ubuntu-security-status` tool does NOT know how to handle that (versus the standard x86_64 aka `amd64` which is in the standard repositories).

As such, this is "Standard Behavior for the tool for any architecture in the `ports.ubuntu.com` repository" because the tool is not aware of how to handle the ubuntu ports repositories for arm64 - this is a known current limitation of the tool.

Comment: Could you use the MY_MIRROR environment variable to fix this? That's what I did for the local mirror.

Comment: @OrganicMarble possibly, but I don't have an arm64 environment to test right now.  Security team just said "it doesn't know what to do with it" and that will apply to any ports.u.c mirror in use - OP's output shows they're using two separate repos with ports in it and that may break things.

Comment: @FedKad I already did, you said it didn't help and I deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

This command has been replaced with `pro security-status` in **Ubuntu 22.10**. A sample run in my ARM system produces an output like this:

```
$ pro security-status 
2036 packages installed:
     1866 packages from Ubuntu Main/Restricted repository
     167 packages from Ubuntu Universe/Multiverse repository
     3 packages no longer available for download

To get more information about the packages, run
    pro security-status --help
for a list of available options.

Main/Restricted packages receive updates until 7/2023.
```